Tor Browser как разрешить сайту обмениваться данными с десктопными приложениями?
У меня есть Unity hub и Nord VPN, но доступ к окну входа (приложение для аутентификации пользователя перенаправляет на сайт где нужно ввести логин и пароль, а затем сайт открывает вспылающее меню которое как-то общается с десктопным приложением) заблокировано провайдером. Пытаюсь войти через Tor Browser, но после входа мне не выскакивает окно с перенаправлением на десктопное приложение.
